# Carousel html to php using database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, carousel

I created a carousel in html/js with a title, caption and an image. I'm trying to transfer it using php but no idea how. I created a table in my database "Test" named "Carousel" with 5 rows (id,Title,Caption,Image and a link) and i input data in the field but no idea on how to select it on php in a carousel form.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="../images/aa1.jpg">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4>
            <p>Caption Caption Caption Caption <a class="label label-primary" href="#" target="_blank">See More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

         <div class="item">
          <img src="../images/aa2.jpg">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4>
            <p>Caption Caption Caption Caption<a class="label label-primary" href="#" target="_blank">See More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="#">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4>
            <p>Caption Caption Caption. <a class="label label-primary" href="#" target="_blank">See More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="#">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4>
            <p>Caption Caption Caption <a class="label label-primary" href="#" target="_blank">See More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <img src="#">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4><a href="#">Title</a></h4>
            <p>Caption Caption Caption <a class="label label-primary" href="#" target="_blank">See More</a></p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->


    <ul class="list-group col-sm-4">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="list-group-item active"><h4>Title</h4></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="list-group-item"><h4>Title</h4></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="list-group-item"><h4>Title</h4></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="list-group-item"><h4>Title</h4></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="list-group-item"><h4>Title</h4></li>
    </ul>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <div class="carousel-controls">
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
      </div>

    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

Is there a way i can transfer this to php/sql so i can update it easily?

Comment: As a strategy you might want to do as little as possible in PHP and do all the heavy lifting in client-side JavaScript. That avoids a lot of wrecking around and trying to make everything perfect in PHP, you can just sketch in the HTML and send over some JSON data that's used to expand on the client into a proper carousel. jQuery has a bunch of plugins that make this super easy.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want to add images to your carousel from a database correct? If so:

Save the location of the `image (filepath)` as a `string` in the `database`.
Use `php` to get all the `filepaths` in the `database`.

```
foreach filepath, echo out the div .item
```

For the `carousel indicator circles`, you can increase a number by 1 in every loop of the `foreach`, or use `sql count`. Though incrementing a number is probably easier.

If you wanted captions in all of them, just also get the caption from the table with the same `Select query` as getting the filepath

Guide:

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT captionTitle, captionContent, imageFilepath FROM carouselContent";

  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  $count = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $count++;
    if($count === 1) echo "<div class='item active'";
    else echo "<div class='item'";
    echo "> Whatever else is in the item here";
```

When you get to adding the image tag:

```
echo "<img src='" . $row['imageFilepath'] . "' alt='carouselImage'>";
```

If you have indicator circles, use a

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
  echo "<carousel indicator code, replacing the carousel indicator slide target integer with $i";
  //Note, this is for Bootstrap Carousels which are incredibly similar to your code
}
```

Comment: tried what you said and come up with this and now it doesnt show anything.
https://pastebin.com/xi9ncKwf
Is there something wrong with the code? I'm kinda new to php

Comment: @JayDoe do you get any errors? Or just no output at all? Have you tried viewing your page source too? (Ctrl + U in chrome)

You also have two sets of carousel controls in that code, after `echo "</div>";` before `<div class="carousel-controls">` You need to close the php part by using `?>`

Furthermore, instead of using escaped double quotation marks (`\"`) You can just use single quotation marks `'`